# Java YAML Configuration to a custom hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, yaml, snakeyaml

I am currently programming a bukkit plugin that stores a bunch of information about the player in a YAML configuration file. Now I want the plugin to read the YAML file when the server starts up and then add on the that information. I have my loader, but I cant use it because my plugin uses a custom map. Here is the code for the map:

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>>
```

And here is the code to get the information from the file:

```
info = (Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>>) ticket.getConfigurationSection("tickets");
```

But when I try to run the plugin with that line of code i get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bukkit.configuration.MemorySection cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

Full code is posted here: http://pastebin.com/Xgu8hwM0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I solved this. I ***HAD*** to use the `Map<String, Object>` but it worked because the way I had it(`Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>>`) that is the second part!

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this is not using a custom map. You already get a `MemorySection` from your configuration.

Work with that. Instead of casting you should use the method: [`getValues(boolean)`](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/configuration/ConfigurationSection.java#L46) which returns a `Map<String, Object>` containing all the relevant information and is specified by the Interface `ConfigurationSection`.

```
ticket.getConfigurationSection("tickets").getValues();
```

See also the relevant excerpt at [bukkit's Configuration API Reference](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Configuration_API_Reference#HashMaps):

> The getValues method will return the values in the
>   ConfigurationSection as a map, it takes a boolean which controls if
>   the nested maps will be returned in the map.

Comment: @Volgel612 If I use the getValues() it returns the `Map<String, Object>` and not `Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>>`

Comment: I have the strong suspicion you're trying to solve the problem wrongly. do you mind adding an excerpt of the relevant configuration file, maybe I can advise better.

Comment: I am not really understanding what your saying. could you mabey make a pastebin for it?